# Illustrator javascript – looping through array of pathItems only affects last item?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm writing an Illustrator javascript to copy selected items onto another layer, then change the fill and stroke of the resulting items, so that they all have no fill, and the same stroke colour. It's mostly working – the duplication part works fine, but looping through an array of the resulting items in order to alter the properties of each item only seems to affect the last item in the array.

```
main();

function main() {
    //Check if there is a document
    if (app.documents.length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        //Check Cutter layer exists, get reference to it if it does
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
        var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;
        if (existCheck(doc.layers, "Cutter")) {
            var cutterLayer = doc.layers.getByName("Cutter");
            //Get reference to selection (as Array)
            var mySelection = app.selection;
            //Iterate through array of selected objects, duplicating each one onto Cutter layer
            for (var i = 0; i < mySelection.length; i++) {
                mySelection[i].duplicate(cutterLayer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);
            }
            currentLayer.hasSelectedArtwork = false;
            var myPathItems = cutterLayer.pathItems;
            for (var i = 0; i < myPathItems.length; i++) {
                myPathItems[i].filled = false;
                myPathItems[i].stroked = true;
                myPathItems[i].strokeWidth = 1;
                myPathItems[i].strokeColor = doc.swatches.getByName("Cutter").color;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Function to check if a names item exists in an array
function existCheck(myArray, name) {
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].name == name) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected all of the referenced pathItems to have a stroke colour of the swatch "Cutter", and no fill – but only the last item does. The other items have no fill or stroke.

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`in `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the version of Javascript that Illustrator uses is years out of date, and "Let" is not recognised.

Comment: Alright you will need to enclose your code within the loop in closure.Because by the time code will be executed loop had already been iterated and i value will be the last value because of that only last element is modified.

Comment: What is the data you are passing in myArray to `existCheck` function?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your for loop with closure

```
/*rewrite your loop like this*/
  for (var i = 0; i < myPathItems.length; i++) {
    (function () {
      var index = i;
      myPathItems[index].filled = false;
      myPathItems[index].stroked = true;
      myPathItems[index].strokeWidth = 1;
      myPathItems[index].strokeColor = doc.swatches.getByName("Cutter").color;
    })();
  }
```

IIFE is used so that the function will run right away. The effect is the same as the original code except for now the variable index is local to IIFE so it will not change every time the variable i changes.

Comment: Thank you again, but that didn't work either. I don't think the problem is with the loop structure itself. Some of the statements within the loop (eg. `myPathItems[index].filled = false;`) are being executed on all items in the array, but other statements (eg. `myPathItems[index].stroked = true;`) are only being executed on the last item. I do really appreciate your help, though.